# fmm, lcprob(m): regress y x

Tags: regression, stata, probit

I am wondering if someone would help me to understand the the stata command posted here:

https://www.stata.com/stata-news/news32-4/spotlight-fmm/

the article explains that the command
fmm 2, lcprob(pchol): regress chol wine

"We hypothesize that an individual may inherit a "high cholesterol" gene and that we have two types of individuals in the population—those with the cholesterol gene and those without. However, we do not know who belongs to each group.

We use fmm to probabilistically classify the sample into groups. By adding the fmm prefix followed by 2, we indicate that we want to fit a model for two underlying subpopulations. We use the lcprob(pchol) option to include parents' cholesterol history as the predictor of the unobserved group, also called the latent class."

I am using probit: fmm 2, lcprob(m): probit y x   where m is the predictor of the unobserved group.

My equation is: ln(L)=ln⁡{p_1* Φ(z)+ p_2*[1- Φ(z)]}

where, Φ(z) = cumulative distribution function on of: beta1 *x1 + beta2 * x2 + ..+ ai + ei    (ei ~ iid)    and

a_i  takes k different values corresponding type of physical condition.

Since types are unobserved, the statistical framework assumes that type k occurs with p_k probability, and assuming k=2 the model estimates the following likelihood function of the mixture distribution

ln(L)=ln⁡{p_1* Φ(z)+ p_2*[1- Φ(z)]}

BUT WHEN WE DO fmm 2, lcprob(m): probit y x     HOW TO WRITE THIS lcprob(m) IN EQUATION?

Maybe, I am not understanding this clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likelihood can be written as

$$\mathcal{L}(\beta) = \sum_{j=1}^{2} \pi(m_i) \prod_{i=1}^{N} f_{ij}(y_{ij},x_{ij},\beta)$$

where $\pi$s are the "mixing" probabilities for each latent class.

Comment: Hello Dimitriy, thank you so much for your help. Just to clarify, the π(m_i): is "m_i" the predictor variable same as "pchol"  in this stata command: "fmm 2, lcprob(pchol): regress chol wine"?

Comment: Yes, I was using your probit command as an example.

Comment: Thank you, Dimitriy.

Comment: @Mahmood If this answered your original question, could you select this as the answer? If not, please let me know what remains unclear.

Comment: Yes, this does answer my original question, certainly. I don't know how to select, any button I have to click (I tried with vote). Just one quick question: this specific technique (with predictor in lcprob) - is there any technical name of this or just probit mixture?

Comment: It's a checkmark on the left below the counter. They are both probit mixtures, but with lcprob you are explicitly modeling the mixing probabilities as a function of m.